# `error C2415: improper operand type` when getting address of a variable

Tags: visual-c++, assembly, x86, offset, inline-assembly

I have this Visual C++ code:

```
 void kopirovaniPrvku(char pole[]){
        _asm{
            mov eax, offset pole;
            mov bl, [eax + 2];
            mov[eax + 7], bl;
            mov bl, [eax + 3];
            mov[eax + 9], bl;
        }
    }

    int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[]){
        char polePrvku[10];
        polePrvku[0] = 0;
        polePrvku[1] = 1;
        polePrvku[2] = 2;
        polePrvku[3] = 3;
        polePrvku[4] = 4;
        polePrvku[5] = 5;
        polePrvku[6] = 6;
        polePrvku[7] = 7;
        polePrvku[8] = 8;
        polePrvku[9] = 9;
        kopirovaniPrvku(polePrvku);
    }
```

I've got this function and I want to use **OFFSET**, but I get this error:

> error C2415: improper operand type.

When I use a **global array** it works without problem.

My question is : Why do I get this error? Is it because paramater **pole** and **polePrvku** have a different addresses? I am not interesting in finding a solution, I just want to understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: Pole is a variable passed on the stack to the function and you can't use `mov` to get the address using offset. Does `lea eax, [pole]` work?

Comment: Yes, lea works. but It doesn't make changes in polePrvku. It doesn't change the numbers.

Comment: I expected that. `Offset` is only usable to get an address if it is at a fixed location in memory. So a global variable has a fixed location in memory and `offset` will work with that. Parameters passed to a function (32-bit code) are pushed onto the stack and don't have a fixed location in memory. `LEA` can be used to get the address of named variables that may be passed on the stack.

Comment: So I can use Offset only when I've got a fixed address (a global variable).

Comment: Any variable with an address that can be resolved at compile time. So it would include static variables in an object or global data. Any variables (in 32-bit code) defined in a function that are marked static can be used with  `offset`. _LEA_ will work for both types (stack based and global/static variables). I generally just use _LEA_ instead of MOV with OFFSET for all cases where I need to get an address.

Comment: Also `char pole[]` in argument declaration is actually `char* pole` and as such you need a `mov eax, pole` not a `lea`.

Comment: @Jester : Good point I didn't even look at the correctness of the existing code.